# Uncaught TypeError: data[id] is undefined | its defined and should work

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea whats wrong please send me a explanation what I did wrong and how to fix it next time so I have know it for next time thanks!

Browser: Firefox

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data[id] is undefined
    go 127.0.0.1/g.html?id=user:29
    <anonymous> 127.0.0.1/g.html?id=user:37
```

Code: (This is from line 7 to line 41)

```
    <script defer>
      function go(data) {
        let query = location.search.slice(1).toLowerCase()
        if (query == "") {
          alert("Sorry, please include a query.")
          return
        }
        let querys = query.split("&")



        if (querys[0].split("=")[0] == "id") {
          let id = querys[0].split("=")[1]
          if (querys[1]) {
            let q = querys[1].split("=")
            if (!q[0] == "scope") {
              alert("Scope value is not valid\n\nCODE: QUERY_SCOPE_INVAILD")
              return
            }
            let root = `/site/ids/${data[id][q[1]]}`
            location.replace(root)
          } else {
            let root = `/site/id/${data[id].main}`
            location.replace(root)
          }
        } else {
          alert("Site ID is not valid\n\nCODE: QUERY_ID_NOT_FOUND")
        }
      }
      // Run code
      go({
        "user": {"main": "user_data"},
      })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change this part:

```
if (querys[1]) {
        let q = querys[1].split("=")
```

to

```
if (querys[1]) {
        let q = querys[1].split(":")
```

Comment: Why though? it doesn't make sense

Comment: 'id=user:29'.split('=') is ['id', 'user:29']. Now you have to split the seconde part on ':' to get the id.